# Vertex pulling problem

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, vertices

I tried 3.18 , 3.22.8, 3.28.6 in QGIS versions, I have the same problem in all of them. When I pull the vertexes, sometimes it gets stuck like this, it selects other points. What is the reason for this?
[image]